# Select All in iOS Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

When selecting text in iOS, you get a "Select, Select All, Speak Sentence" popup as soon as you place the cursor. This doesn't seem to work in Safari where trying select something only brings up "Copy, Define, Share".

So how does one trigger "Select All" on a webpage shown in Safari?

[image]

Comment: As an alternative, I have Voice Dream installed and you can use 'Save to Voice Dream' by tapping the share button in Safari, and read the text using Voice Dream TTS

Answer (score 5):

‘Select, Select All, Speak Sentence’ are the options shown when there is no current selection. In your screenshot, a selection has been made, so the options change to be contextual to your selection, namely ‘Copy, Look Up, Share…’.

You can only bring up the first set of options without a selection, therefore this is only possible in a text input or textarea. You can make the entire page editable, thereby being able to place the cursor within without a selection, by running the following JavaScript in a Shortcut:

```js
document.body.contentEditable = "true";
```

[image: Edit Webpage shortcut screenshot]

Comment: Is `document.body.contentEditable = "true";` a persistent setting? Is there anything else needed in the Shortcut? How do you even use that in a Shortcut?

Comment: @user No, similarly to JS run in a desktop browser's console, the setting applies to the current JS context which will likely be replaced on page navigation. The Shortcut only needs to consist of that one action to run the above JavaScript in the webpage.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you'd actually show a working Shortcut workflow. The first paragraph of your answer is very informative; however the lack of an example Shortcut workflow showing how to properly use the JavaScript snippet makes for a marginal answer.

Comment: @user I've added a screenshot of the shortcut. Unfortunately I can't share the actual shortcut itself as the sharing functionality appears to be broken on iOS 13, but I will add one when I can or you are welcome to add a link to the shortcut yourself.

Comment: Even with the screenshot this does provide directions, the steps necessary to actually create and use what you posted. I'm using iOS 12.x and can't recreate what you're showing. Not a big deal as at this moment I do not need to use this and was jut trying to get you to improve the answer so anyone wanting to select all text in a Safari window would be able to follow steps to create and use the JavaScript snippet and as presently written I think the average user will be lost.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. These days you also need to add "completion(0);" to the JavaScript and set up the share action a little bit differently.